# Using type variable as a return type in a generic class

Tags: generics, return-type, type-variables

```
class C <E extends C>{
    E inC;
    public  E doStuff(E e,C<E> e2){
        return e.getE();
   }
   public  E getE(){
    return inC;
   }
}
```

The above code results in compiler error,and I don't understand why.The
doStuff() method returns a 'E type' , since E extends C, any method that's expecting C can accept an 'E' and vice-versa,then why do I get the error?
I saw this question in a mock test of OCPJP.
Thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a mistake and referred to `C` without giving it its parameters when you say `E extends C`.

If you define the class as

```
class C<E extends C<E>> {
```

your code will work. (This kind of idiom is unfortunately common in Java; for example, you say `<T extends Comparable<T>>` rather than merely `<T extends Comparable>`; this is necessary because there's not a way to refer to "this type" in a signature)

---

Without the `C<E>` clarification, you only know that `e.getE()` produces a `C`, but NOT necessarily an `E` -- it could be a *different* subclass of `C`. Why is that?

We know that `E` is `C<Something>`, but we don't know what `Something` is. So `e.getE()` is a `Something`, *not* necessarily an `E`.

For example, you allow a `class A extends C<B> {}` whose `doStuff` returns a `B` rather than an `A` -- which is the reason the compiler is mad.

Comment: thank you for your reply @Curtis F , this answer really helped me,and yeah the code works fine if I define the class as :class C<E extends C<E>> {